# How do I service the Apple Wireless Keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

I recently got a little bit of water on my Apple Wireless Keyboard and now when I press a key others are registering at the same time along with it. For example when I press <kbd>shift</kbd>, *t* and/or *r* is also sometime registered. Also when I press:

- <kbd>e</kbd>, *t* and *r* are also registered, typing out *etr*
- <kbd>r</kbd>, *t* is also registered, typing out *rt*
- <kbd>t</kbd>, *t* is registered multiple times giving an output of *ttttttt*
- <kbd>f</kbd>, *g* and *r* are also registered, typing out *fgr*
- <kbd>g</kbd>, *f* and *t* are also registered, typing out *fgt*
- <kbd>v</kbd>, *b* and *r* are also registered, typing out *bvr*
- <kbd>b</kbd>, *v* and *t* are also registered, typing out *bvt*

These are the only keys that cause issue and they also happen to be around the area the small ammount of liquid was spilt. Is it possible that the liquid has messed up the registering system of the keyboard so that those keys are often registered incorrectly?

If so, how might I go about cleaning the keyboard out?

---

**Update:**

It has worsened now and the <kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd> and <kbd>f</kbd> keys do not register at all now.

Comment: If it was soda, coffee or another "sticky" liquid when dry, I'd say there is hope. But since it was pure water, I doubt the neighboring keys are being pressed. It sounds like you have corrosion of the circuit board and likely a short circuit. These things cannot be fixed I'm afraid. And the Apple keyboard is glued together, a design that makes it nigh impossible to service.

Comment: It has worsened now and the r, t and f keys do not register at all now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are lucky just wait a day or a week for it to dry out completely.

You could try to clean individual keyboard keys (the contact area) but you will have to take it apart.

That is doable but requires some [skills](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCpf5xqiK4I) like in this video or [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hDkFCm57ec).

If you are not lucky you will have to replace it.

Comment: I managed to clean the contact areas beneath the keys by soaking them in isopropyl which successfully solved the problem. +1 ✔